# Strange problem with additional space when figure floats away

Tags: fontspec, floatrow, scrbook

I am using `fontspec`, `floatrow` and `subfig` together. When a figure floats away an additional space is inserted at the place where the figure is in the text. In cases in which the line before the figure is as long as the text width a space is put at the beginning of the next line, which disturbes the layout very much. When I comment out one of the packages, the space disappears. The problem seems to be also `scrbook`-specific, since when I change to `article`, the problem is gone. Is there anything I can do about this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{forest}



\begin{document}
text, more text, more text. In so-called cartographic approaches, it is assumed that every morphosyntactic feature corresponds to an independent syntactic
head. For an explicitly formalized proposal, in which each feature is processed in its combination, 
see. Stabler's \emph{Minimalist     Grammars} are discussed in more detail in Section 3.1.
\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\begin{forest}
[ForceP
        []
        [Force$'$
                [Force$^0$]
                [TopP*
                        []
                        [Top$'$
                                [Top$^0$]
                                [FocP
                                        []
                                        [Foc$'$
                                                [Foc$^0$]
                                                [TopP*
                                                        []
                                                        [Top$'$
                                                                [Top$^0$]
                                                                [FinP
                                                                        []
                                                                        [Fin$'$
                                                                                [Fin$^0$]
                                                                                [IP]]]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}

\caption{\label{Abbildung-Rizzi}Syntactic structure of sentences following Rizzi}
\end{figure}
The functional categories Force, Top, Foc and
Fin correspond to clause type, topic, focus and finiteness. It is assumed that movement always targets a specifier
position. Topics and focussed elements are always moved to the specifier position of the corresponding phrase. Topics can precede or follow focussed
elements, which is why there are two topic projections: one above and one below FocP. Topic phrases


\end{document}
```

---

to help debugging, a more minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}



\begin{document}

A B

A
\begin{figure}[p]
XXXX
\end{figure}
B


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should type `\end{figure}%` here.

Comment: Isn't it better to add the `figure` environment between paragraphs?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi you should not need the `%` latex uses "space hacks" in horizontal mode specifically to avoid this. Something is interfering....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Imho floatrow. I can reproduce the problem with book and floatrow alone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes looking now...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer added a simpler example to the question

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can't reproduce the issue (TL 2014/MacTeX).

Comment: @egreg: Add \RequirePackage{fixltx2e} then you should see the space in Davids example too. (I'm not longer sure that KOMA + subfig or caption are not involved, I think I had a side effect from lipsum.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The OP's example has no call to `fixltx2e`. It seems I was right in never loading it. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: But he has perhaps/probably the new latex which imho incorporates the changes.  At least `\begin{figure}[x]` gives an error in tl15 as it would in tl14 + fixltx2e.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, because `forest` is broken with the new LaTeX (at least until today's update).

Comment: @egreg: Worked fine for me with lualatex.

Comment: I had texlive 2014 and reverted to 2013 with no updates since some pgf stuff did not work. Ulrike was involved with tracing this down and it is now a bug report somewhere. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: I am now on texlive 2015 and the problem is still there. I use xelatex. I did add a `%` to some of the finished books, but it happens with new texts where I copy from papers, so this is not a really scalable solution ...

Comment: I see nothing strange with TeX Live 2016